# jQuery image folder name change dynamically without console error

Tags: jquery

By default all images are loading from **defaultFolder** `(.html pages)` and by using jQuery I am replacing the **defaultFolder** with **NewFolder** like below..

**index.html**

```
<html>
  <head><title>Test</title></head>
    <body>
      <img src="images/defaultFolder/client-logo.png" alt="Client" />
    </body>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/myscript-init.js"></script>
</html>
```

**myscript-init.js file**

```
jQuery(function () {
  var img = jQuery("img");
  img.each(function () {
    var src = jQuery(this).attr('src');
    if (src.indexOf('defaultFolder/') > -1) { 
      jQuery(this).attr('src', src.replace("defaultFolder", 'NewFolder'));
    }
  });
});
```

Tried with **jQuery(document).ready(function () {** also without luck :(

> Everything is working as expected... but still I am able to see the
>   errors in console which is annoying :( ... Because of these I am
>   finding difficulties in actual error handling..

Is there anyway to avoid this please?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is the src hardcoded into the html? If so, that's your problem... your html loads, then jQuery does it's magic, but by then the browser has tried to load the images ergo console errors

Comment: @DarrenSweeney No... that script is coming form external file (**init.js**) and inside html pages */Images/defaultFolder/image1.jpg* etc... So, no other opton?

Comment: at `jQuery(this).attr('src', src.replace("defaultFolder", 'NewFolder');` this line some syntax error you missed to close `attr(` function it should be `jQuery(this).attr('src', src.replace("defaultFolder", 'NewFolder'));`

Comment: Hi **@Curiousdev** Thanks for pointing out. I missed that only on this post not in my code. However I have double checked the same and issue is still there. **PS:** I have corrected and updated the same now.

Comment: @Reddy, why don't you just change folder in the html code itself? Why do you need jQuery for that?

Comment: **@Aravind**, This has more than 200+ pages and I am controlling all the client related text from init.js file. Client provides their images and I just need to replace the same in client folder. Otherwise I have to change all the 200+ pages.